# When was the power play rule introduced in cricket?

Tags: cricket, trivia, history

When the **Power Play** rule introduced in limited overs cricket?

Comment: THe First instance is in 1980 in Australia.

Comment: The answer by him056 is clear enough. However, for future references, instead of asking such questions (facts) you could directly search them on google on refer wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerplay_%28cricket%29) the powerplay rule was introduces in ODI in 1980 in Australia.

Looking at the [series archives in 1980s](http://static.espncricinfo.com/db/ARCHIVE/1980S/1980-81/), only ODI series in Australia was [World Series Cricket](http://static.espncricinfo.com/db/ARCHIVE/1980S/1980-81/OD_TOURNEYS/WSC/).